# Retriving exact text from json output

Tags: java, json

I am using unofficial ginger grammar checking API, which returns the result in json. I want to extract the correction it gives in the text provided as input.

I have done it,but it only work as static i.e. I have to manually adjust the code and then it return output.

Following is my code -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONString;
//import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
public class Demo {


    static class urllib {
        public static StringBuffer urlopen(URL url) {
            try {
                //URL u = new URL(url);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String str = null;
                while((str = in.readLine())!=null) {
                    sb.append(str);
                }
                in.close();
                return sb;
            } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        StringBuffer result = null;
        String finalResult = null;
        StringBuffer response;
        String finalResponse = null;
        String finalText=null;
        try{                         
            //connections settings
            String data = new String("a apple");
            finalText=data;
            String s[]=data.split(" ");
            int i=0;
            String text =s[0] ;
            for(i=1;i<s.length;i++)
            {
                text=text+"+"+s[i];
            }
            System.out.println(text);
            String Finaldata= new String(""+text);
            URL url = new URL("http://services.gingersoftware.com/Ginger/correct/json/GingerTheText?lang=US&clientVersion=2.0&apiKey=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX&text="+Finaldata);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput (true);             
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            System.out.println("connection done");

            JSONObject json ;
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try
            {
                response =urllib.urlopen(url);
                finalResponse= response.toString();
                //System.out.println("final response"+finalResponse);
                json = new JSONObject(finalResponse);
                //System.out.println(json);
                finalResult=json.toString();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            //This stores corrected text

           String temp = new JSONObject(finalResult)
                   .getJSONArray("LightGingerTheTextResult").getJSONObject(0)
                   .getJSONArray("Suggestions").getJSONObject(0)
                   .getString("Text");
           System.out.println(temp);

          //This stores which part is corrected            
           String temp1 = new JSONObject(finalResult)
                   .getJSONArray("LightGingerTheTextResult").getJSONObject(0)
                   .getJSONArray("Suggestions").getJSONObject(1)
                   .getString("Text");
           System.out.println(temp1);

           temp=temp.toLowerCase();
           temp1=temp1.toLowerCase();

          String newString= finalText.replace(temp1, temp);

          System.out.println(newString);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Here everytime i need to change values of "getJsonObject()" every time. Is there any way from which I can do this dynamically or any other way of extracting text like converting json object to java object,but I don't have any idea about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Is using gson an option?

Comment: I do not have any clear idea about it.

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson - Look into utilizing the `fromJson()` method

Comment: can you replace  this line  ** response =urllib.urlopen(url);     ** with static JSON so we can run it?